# Probability of rolling $3$ dice $n$ times with a specific sum

Tags: probability, dice

Imagine we're rolling $3$ dice. How many times do we need to roll them so we get a sum of $15$ with a probability of $0.6$?

What I got so far:

We're throwing the dices $n$ times (this hints at Bernoulli trials...?)

The event we're watching is:

$A$: the sum of the rolled numbers is $15$

We have that the probability of $P_n(A) = 0.6$

There're $10$ combinations to get a sum of $15$. How do I proceed?

Comment: Well, what's the probability of getting a $15$ on a single roll of the three dice?

Comment: That'd be 10/6^3

Comment: Agreed.  Call it $p$ (for simplicity).  What's the probability that you don't get a $15$ in $n$ throws?

Comment: (1-p)^n I guess?

Comment: Agreed.  So you want the least $n$ such that this is $≤.4$.  Take logs.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate it a lot :)

Comment: Not a problem.  Good work.

Comment: Instead of doing it this way, is there a way to solve this problem using the equation for bernoulli trials?

Comment: I'd say this method was using Bernoulli trials...not sure how else to do it.

Comment: If n = ? k = 1(we want the experiment to appear only once) then
0.6 >= C(n, k) p^k q^(n-k)

Comment: no...it could appear more than once, you just don't want it to appear $0$ times.  I think you'll end up just repeating the calculation you've already done.

Comment: "I think you'll end up just repeating the calculation you've already done."

That's what I was asking, because on our exam we'll receive less points if we solve it the way we did it above.

Comment: Ah, sorry.  To my mind the method we followed is the most efficient, but of course you may be asked to show understanding of a different path.  Not sure I can help with that.  If you come up with a different method, post it as a solution below.  I'll gladly check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability of rolling a $15$ is $\frac5{108}$. The probability of not rolling a $15$ after $n$ rolls would be
$$
\left(\frac{103}{108}\right)^n
$$
Thus, the probability of rolling a $15$ within the first $n$ rolls is
$$
1-\left(\frac{103}{108}\right)^n
$$
Find the $n$ so that this is greater than $0.6$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, appreciated.